# Passing an array with redirect. Problems with »reload«.

Tags: laravel-5

Framework is Laravel. I am passing an array with the redirect method from a controller like this:

```
$serializeThrowsArray = serialize($throwsArray);
return redirect()->route('pages.result')
    ->with( ['serializeThrowsArray' => $serializeThrowsArray] );
```

to a named route:

```
Route::get('/result', ['as' => 'pages.result', function() {

    $serializeThrowsArray = session()->get('serializeThrowsArray');
    $throwsArray = unserialize($serializeThrowsArray);

    return view('pages.result', ['throwsArray' =>$throwsArray]);
}]);
```

which loads the next page:

```
@section('content')
    @foreach ($throwsArray as $throw)
    {{$throw}},
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Everything work as it should, except when i hit F5(reload) and get the next error msg: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" and the next code is higlighted:

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $throwsArray; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); 
foreach($__currentLoopData as $throw): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop 
= $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

I know is a problem with session-flash that has been cleared. Is there a work around or another way to pass an array with redirect?

Comment: I guess it depends a bit on what is acceptable for you, your users and what other requirements are. You could also just pass the data as `GET` parameters or as one base64 encoded argument, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try

return->view('pages.result')